# Is it possible to configure an IAM role for an ECS task ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I need to do some initialisation that needs access to certain AWS resources during my docker entrypoint.

My application could also do with implicit role based access to AWS rather than configuring the key pair in app config.

How do IAM roles work in tasks ? I could only find IAM role documentation on ECS container instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ECS task will assume the IAM Role/Instance Profile of the given container. There is no task level way to assign a different IAM Role.

[Amazon ECS Container Instance IAM Role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html)

> The Amazon ECS container agent makes calls to the Amazon ECS API
>   actions on your behalf, so container instances that run the agent
>   require an IAM policy and role for the service to know that the agent
>   belongs to you. Before you can launch container instances and register
>   them into a cluster, you must create an IAM role for those container
>   instances to use when they are launched. This requirement applies to
>   container instances launched with the Amazon ECS-optimized AMI
>   provided by Amazon, or with any other instances that you intend to run
>   the agent on.

Comment: Fair enough. I can work with that. Thanks for confirming that.

Comment: @HassanSyed while this is true there are people out there that have figured out how to get around the limitation such as https://github.com/dump247/ec2metaproxy

Comment: This answer is very poorly worded: Despite Amazon's terrible naming scheme, the "container instance role" is NOT "the role of the given container"!
The container instance is just their confusing term for the EC2 instance that belongs to that ECS cluster, meaning that the "container instance role" is referring to the EC2 instance role.

Comment: As far as I understand, the reason they came up with this confusing terminology ("container instance" instead of just "EC2 instance") is because, if you're running ECS using the Fargate launch type (as opposed to the EC2 launch type), then it's technically not running on EC2s, it's running on infrastructure managed by AWS.

Comment: For more details, see their documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_instances.html

Answer (score 10):

Since version 1.11.0 ECS container agent supports task IAM roles, thus accepted answer is no longer true. Though, I doubt it was in the first place, because [ECS container instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_instances.html) is an EC2 instance that hosts Docker container instances and is managed by ECS container agent.

[IAM Roles for Tasks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html)

> With IAM roles for Amazon ECS tasks, you can specify an IAM role that can be used by the containers in a task. Applications must sign their AWS API requests with AWS credentials, and this feature provides a strategy for managing credentials for your applications to use, similar to the way that Amazon EC2 instance profiles provide credentials to EC2 instances.

Comment: Suppose I have added a taskRole to access my S3 buckets and the EC2 instance IAM role have access to DynamoDB table along with the mandate "AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role", Will I be able to access both of these services or taskRole overrides the permissions from the EC2 IAM role?